# Django Rest Framework nested serializers AttributeError 'RelatedManager' object has no attribute

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

**Full Error**

Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `segments` on serializer `BackboneLineSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `RelatedManager` instance.
Original exception text was: 'RelatedManager' object has no attribute 'segments'.

I can't figure out why I'm getting this error. I'm using what I think is the exact same code elsewhere with it working. The only thing I can think of is I may have changed the related_name on the backbone_line field of the BackboneLineSegments model from something else to 'segments'. All migrations have been applied, and I don't know why it would be causing issues. Maybe the database doesn't update the new related_name correctly? I'm using Postgres in case it matters.

**Models**

```
class BackboneLine(models.Model):
    sub_area = models.ForeignKey(
        SubArea,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        null=True,
        related_name='backbone_lines')
    source = models.ForeignKey(
        Enclosure,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        null=True,
        related_name='backbone_lines_out'
    )
    destination = models.OneToOneField(
        Enclosure,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        null=True,
        related_name='backbone_line_in'
    )

    @property
    def label(self):
        return f'{self.source.box_number} - {self.destination.box_number}'

class BackboneLineSegment(models.Model):
    location = models.LineStringField()
    buried = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    backbone_line = models.ForeignKey(
        BackboneLine,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='segments'
    )

    @property
    def long_lat(self):
        return [list(coord_pair) for coord_pair in self.location]

    @property
    def lat_long(self):
        return [(cords[1], cords[0]) for cords in self.location.coords]

class SubArea(models.Model):
    label = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    area = models.ForeignKey(
        Area, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, related_name='sub_areas')
    fiber_switch = models.ForeignKey(
        'FiberSwitch', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, related_name='sub_areas'
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.label
```

**Serializers**

```
class BackboneLineSegmentSerializer(GeoFeatureModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = BackboneLineSegment
        geo_field = 'location'
        fields = ['location', 'buried']

class BackboneLineSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    segments = BackboneLineSegmentSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = BackboneLine
        fields = ['label', 'segments']

class SubAreaSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    enclosures = EnclosureSerializer(many=True)
    backbone_lines = BackboneLineSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = SubArea
        fields = ['label', 'enclosures', 'backbone_lines']
```

**Code Throwing Error**

```
sub_area = SubArea.ocbjects.get(pk=1)
sub_area_serialier = SubAreaSerializer(sub_area)
```

Comment: What object did you pass to the serializer?

Comment: Try using `backbone_line` instead of `segments` in your `BackboneLineSerializer`.

Comment: I get the same error but replacing 'segments' with 'backbone_line'.

Comment: There is actually one more layer of nesting above this, and I'm passing an object obtained from querying that model. This may be the issue, and the relate_name change sent me in the wrong direction. I'll edit my question with more of my code. @BrianDestura